# How to get a font file in production

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts

I have a react.js app up and running. I wanted to change the font to Galano Grotesque Bold. I downloaded the files and followed the tutorial here:
https://esfonts.pro/articulo/como-instalar-una-fuente#web

I have this style.css file:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Galano Grotesque';
src: local('Galano Grotesque Bold'), local('Galano-Grotesque-Bold'),
    url('GalanoGrotesque-Bold.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('GalanoGrotesque-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
    url('GalanoGrotesque-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: 700;
font-style: normal;
```

}

I import it in App.css like this:

```
@import url("fonts/roboto/style.css");

.App {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.zoom {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Galano Grotesque', Bold;
}
```

It's working perfectly in localhost. The problem comes when I deploy this app (using netlify). I see the following error and the font is not correct:

[image]

I understand that these files are being blocked by cord policy. I've read that I should do the request using HTTPS but I don't know how to do it.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: I don't think this it's a CORS error. It may be a license issue. If the font is not licensed for use on the web, you can't just take it and throw it in a `@font-face` rule and have it work.

Comment: so how can I import it? I've seen a WordPress app with this font